# generate column chart with java

Tags: java, charts, pdfbox

I must create a column chart via java but don't know which library to use for that purpose. That chart should look like this one:
[image]

Can you guys offer me a good library?
PS: after generating this chart i must generate pdf file with pdfbox and import the chart.

Comment: Strictly speaking questions asking for library recommendations are off-topic on stack overflow...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you look at [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/).